# how to change HTML page content before it loads in browser

Tags: html, dom

I wanted to change(modify OR delete some div/tag) the HTML page content before it get loaded
in the client browser.

Please help me to know what kind of plugin/BHO/scripts should I use and how can I inject them tot he browser so that whenever user loads a page, my component would be able to modify it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Regards
Ashish

Comment: why you want to change the HTML before loading in browser.  There is no use

Comment: at server side don't generate what you don't want to send to browser

Comment: try  [`chrome extensions`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html) ?

Comment: Do you want to serve different versions of the same site depending on OS/Browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide `BODY` element contents or `BODY` element itself via CSS:

```css
BODY {
    display: none;
}
```

`hidden` class should be added right inside `HEAD` section (while `<body>` opening tag is not even encountered by browser yet):

```js
$(document.documentElement).addClass('hidden');
```

and then unhide it in `ready()` handler:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document.documentElement).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Hiding `BODY` element statically is bad for cases when JS execution is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whats going on here but you could display none the body then make the changes then display block when done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve different versions of the site depending on the client you might want to look into that one: http://mobiledetect.net/

It's using the HTTP-Header information to determines what content to serve.

Comment: thanks for info. But I don't have control on the server side code. Whenever my client uses browsers(IE/FF/Chrome) to load any html page, I should be able to make a change in the HTML, before browsers display the content

Comment: In that case you might wanna look into the same technique with JS? http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Comment: I have seen the above link, but getting confuse. How do I insert this java script to any webpage which is coming as a response to browser HTTP request.